# Prolog: Finding 2 times of a list numbers and putting the number and its double in a list

Tags: list, recursion, prolog, nested-lists

I'm new to Prolog and I've been trying to create a predicate in Prolog which finds the double of a list of numbers and putting the number and its double in one single list. For example:

```
?- double_list([2,3,6,10], List).
List = [[2, 4], [3, 6], [6, 12], [10, 20]].
```

This is the code I've done so far:

```
double_list([],[]).
double_list([H|T], [[H, double]| List]):-
    double is (H*2),
    double_list(T, List).
```

I don't know where I went wrong. I keep on getting `false.` when trying to run the program.

Comment: When you step through the program's execution, at what point does it behave incorrectly?

Comment: I tried using trace, it says Fail: (8) double is 2*2 ? creep. But since I'm I'm still not familiar with prolog, I missed the upper-case letter mistake.

Answer (score 5):

Variables in Prolog start with either an underscore or an upper case letter. The issue in your code is that you wrote `double` instead of `Double`. Correcting your code to:

```
double_list([],[]).
double_list([H|T], [[H, Double]| List]):-
    Double is H*2,
    double_list(T, List).
```

gives you the expected answer to your query:

```
| ?- double_list([2,3,6,10], List).

List = [[2, 4], [3, 6], [6, 12], [10, 20]]
yes
```

Some Prolog systems are able to detect the error in your code. For example, using SICStus Prolog, we get:

```
* invalid LHS in arithmetic expression: double
```